# d3.js drawing a pie chart with multiple columns of a record

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart

I have this data structure:

> [
>                             {x:1,comp:63.79,h:21.74,l:7.25,edu:8.7},
>                             {x:2,comp:63.79,h:21.74,l:7.25,edu:8.7},
>                             {x:3,comp:57.99,h:21.74,l:7.25,edu:8.7},
>                             {x:4,comp:56.54,h:21.74,l:7.25,edu:8.7},
>                             {x:5,comp:50.74,h:21.74,l:7.25,edu:8.7},
>                             {x:6,comp:36.24,h:21.74,l:0,edu:8.7},
>                             {x:7,comp:34.8,h:0,l:7.25,edu:8.7},
>                             {x:8,comp:30.45,h:0,l:7.25,edu:8.7},
>                             {x:9,comp:34.8,h:0,l:0,edu:8.7},
>                             {x:10,comp:34.8,h:0,l:7.25,edu:8.7}
>                           ];

I am trying to make a pie chart representation.
I tried learning from the d3 tutorials but, those are not so useful in this scenario.
The tutorials only work for linear structures like [10,20,30,40].
But in my case, I have to make one pie for each record and plus each record has 4 parameters to include in a pie.
I realize (as per tutorial understanding) that I need to make arc generators for each line per property something like that. But cant find a way to do so. Also, it seems unfeasible.
Specially bcoz, you I will have to write some thing like (as per my attempt on a linear structure):

```
        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
              .value(function(d){ return d; });

    var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
              .data(pie(data))
              .enter()
              .append("g")
              .attr("class", "arc");

    arcs.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill", function(d){ return color(d.data); });
```

Is there a way out....I was thinking I should revamp the data structure or at least change it before using it.

Thanks is Advance !

Comment: Hello ! Do you solve the problem ? I try to do the same thing and it's very difficult to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't even remember now on what I did with this.